# Switch statement in a C# calculator

Tags: c#, calculator, percentage

The calculator can't calculate percentage operations. I will provide the switch statement below. I hope you can help me!

It is only the last `case "%": number = (percentage / 100) * totalNumber;` that doesn't work.

The debugger says:

> Control cannot fall through from one case label to another.

```
private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        switch (operationPerformed) {
            case "+":
                textBox_Result.Text=(resultValue + Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "-":
                textBox_Result.Text = (resultValue - Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "*":
                textBox_Result.Text = (resultValue * Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "/":
                textBox_Result.Text = (resultValue / Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "%":
                number = (percentage / 100) * totalNumber;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

I expect it to calculate the percentage of a certain number, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Look at the other `case` branches (which apparently don't produce a compiler error). What do these other `case` branches have in common that is missing in your `case` branch with `number = (percentage / 100) * totalNumber;`? If you noticed what is missing in your `case` branch, it would perhaps be a good idea to consult the documentation to learn what the purpose/function of that missing bit is ;-) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#the-switch-section)

Comment: You're missing a `break;`after `number = (percentage / 100) * totalNumber;`

Comment: *One of these case blocks is not like the others...*

Comment: Googling "Control cannot fall through from one case label to another." immediately gives me a solution in the first result, try that next time.

Comment: remove default line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check this and please don't add pseudocode

```
case "%":
    textBox_Result.Text = (Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text) * resultValue / 100.0).ToString();
```

Comment: The the debugger says: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string'.

Comment: check my edit but think about it why might the compiler gives this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you make a mistake after case "%" :

Actual formula for Calculating Percentage is: **(Part / Whole) * 100**

you should try something like this:

```
case "%":
   result = (obtained / total) * 100; 
   break;
```